# Constant unindent errors within def functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I'm writing a program that uses exceptions to handle errors from multiple text files, one of which being empty. If it's empty, I need to print out a statement saying said file is empty. I have tried 'except EOFError', but that's not correct, so I'm currently trying os.stat. Anyways I'm getting an unindent error after the colon and I do not know why, as I believe I've formatted everything correctly.

Code:

```
def main():
    process_file("good_data.txt")
    process_file("bad_data.txt")
    process_file("empty_file.txt")
    process_file("does_not_exist.txt")

def process_file(param_str_file_name):

    #Variables
    num_rec = 0
    total = 0
    average = 0

  if os.stat(param_str_file_name).st_size:
    print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, " is empty. Cannot calculate average\n")
  else:
      try:
          file_name = open(param_str_file_name, 'r')

          print("Processing file", param_str_file_name)

          one_score = file_name.readline()
  
          while one_score != "":
              one_score_int = int(one_score)
              num_rec = num_rec + 1

              one_score = file_name.readline()

              total += one_score_int
              average = total / num_rec

          file_name.close()

        print("\tRecord count = ", num_rec)
        print("\tTotal        = ", total)
        print("\tAverage      = ", f"{average:.2f}", "\n")

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, " File not found\n")

    except ValueError:
        print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, "contains non-numeric data\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: If the posted code is exactly what you have in your python file right now, unfortunately it doesn't look indented correctly.

Comment: I advise you use an editor like PyCharm community edition. It checks and shows unindent errors.